# My first django app - how to import templates?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-3.1

I am creating my first django app in django 3.1.1. There are video tutorials for old django versions and they don't always work... I want to create HTML pages for both home and about sections. I have already written some HTML files, but the

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

doesn't want to work. I add my file tree for you to see the structure of files.

```
RemoveBigFile
    ├── RBF1module
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── RemoveBigFile
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── views.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── asgi.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── RemoveBigFile.sublime-project
    ├── RemoveBigFile.sublime-workspace
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    └── templates
        ├── about.html
        └── home.html
```

And that is the error message I get:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.1.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
home.html
```

Django also asks me to put my templates in one of main django installation directories called templates and as far as I know, if I do so, I won't be able to send my app to other people (and that's what I intend to do with it after I am finished).
I use my RemoveBigFile/RemoveBigFile views.py to point django to HTML templates.

EDIT: as requested, I add my templates definition from settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

As I see, there is nothing in DIRS. Should I put the path to my templates in DIRS parentheses?

I also have one more question - is it better to have templates in the folder where manage.py is or where settings.py is?

Comment: Post your `settings.py` please. Does Django know that `/templates` is your template directory?

Comment: by default, Django looks for templates in the following (rather deeply nested) folder hierarchy: app_name/templates/app_name/template.html. And yes, the app_name gets repeated in the templates folder, that's not a typo. If you have not otherwise specified a place, in your settings.py file, for it to look for your templates, it will not find them unless you use this (admittedly awkward) folder structure.

Comment: All right @Selcuk - you can look at my settings.py section about templates.

Comment: @m.arthur - please see the contents of my settings.py :) Where should I specify the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, found it myself with your inspiration :)
Thank you, @Selcuk and @m.arthur. Thanks for contributing @Mahmoud Ishag too :)

The answer lies in there I mustn't have created this app as a project and there was a short string missing in templates:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

namely this one:

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
```

Please compare my code from main post to this one.

Answer (score -1):

Django look for the template in folder called `templates` you need to create that folder inside your app folder and put `home.html` inside it.

Comment: I have already done this. Scheme through the tree I provided in the main post